# Android audioReceiver BroadcastReceiver (Android OS Bug)

Tags: java, android, debugging, google-api, broadcastreceiver

I tried to create a audioReceiver Broadcast. To allow my user to ONLY listen to music if the HeadSet in plug-in.

Here is the code :

```
private BroadcastReceiver audioReceiver  = new BroadcastReceiver()
{   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        headsetIsPluggedIn = (intent.getExtras().getInt("state")==1); 
        if(headsetIsPluggedIn) //plugged
        {   Log.d("", "BroadcastReceiver - Unmute sound");
            audio.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
        }
        else //unplugged
        {   Log.d("", "BroadcastReceiver - Mute sound");
            audio.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);

            // Inform user
            Toast.makeText(DuplicatedPlayerActivity.this, "Please plug in your headset to enjoy the sound.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (HEADSET_ONLY) { registerReceiver(audioReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)); }
```

Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.juno.brheadset.HeadsetStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

OK, Here is the fun part. If you restart the device, run my app. This function will not work.

If you insert the headset jack in the phone at lest once! quit my app, restart the app. The function will work fine, until the user restart the phone again.

Now, why does this function only works if the user insert the jack in the phone?

Answer (score 2):

"Now, Why does this function only works if the user insert the jack in the phone ?" --> Because you have written your code inside the receiver of action "android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG". Your code will only execute when you receive the headset_plug broadcast.

Comment: or, how can you simulate headset plugin in and out ?

Comment: You can do this only in your application. Doing this even in other music players will take a lot of effort. If you want it to work in your application simply check if headset is plugged and based on that issue play or not. And please upvote if I answered correctly.

Comment: You can send a fake broadcast from command line to simulate headset plug.

Comment: You can use:                                                                                               adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG               to send fake broadcast from command line.